# Kohana Auth weird error message on login

Tags: json, kohana, authentication

I've got the Kohana Auth up and running lovely except for one minor thing. 
Using the Model_User that extends Model_Auth_User, When logging in with correct username and wrong password, I get a json response of {"username":"login.username.invalid"}. Every other error works great. This is the only thing stumping me at the mo. Any ideas?
User does exist as I can log in with right username and right password, just right username and wrong password produces this. It looks like some sort of json error to be honest login(submit).username(input).invalid(type of error) = {"username":"login.username.invalid"}. I can't work out what's causing this!!

Answer (score 0):

modules/auth/classes/model/auth/user.php:

```
if ($this->loaded() AND Auth::instance()->login($this, $array['password'], $remember))
{
    if (is_string($redirect))
    {
        // Redirect after a successful login
        Request::instance()->redirect($redirect);
    }

    // Login is successful
    $status = TRUE;
}
else
{
    $array->error('username', 'invalid');
}
```

So, this error is returned no matter if username or password is valid. It's up to you to define which message file it's supposed to be using for retrieving validation error text (it should be something like "username or password incorrect", for security purposes so that the eventual cracker doesn't really know what the error is about).